# Cross-compile program can't find SDL2 headers

Tags: c++, sdl, cross-compiling, autotools, mxe

I'm working on a project in `c++` that uses autotools for easy cross-compile. I've `sudo make install`'d [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) on my system. When just using `./configure`, and thus using `g++`, things run smoothly. However, using `./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32`, I run into this error:

```
In file included from Game.cpp:1:0:
Game.hpp:4:22: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

After fishing around Google all day, I can't seem to find an indicator as to why. I know that when compiling on Win(currently on Ubuntu 15.04), the headers are named differently for SDL, but I'm still using a Unix compiler, according to my understanding. Do I need to have separate source for Windows, with a different include? I monitored the mxe install for errors and received none, so I can't conceive of that being the issue.

If needed, I can provide a more complete picture of the environment, but I believe this to perhaps be an OS specific error/caveat.

Comment: Do you actually have SDL.h file or is it named differently? What happens when you add `-I/path/to/SDL2/` in your compiler options? What does `pkg-config --cflags SDL2` say?

Comment: I'll try the -I flag approach and report back. `sdl2-config --cflags` outputs : `-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT`. `SDL.h` exists in `/usr/include/SDL2/`.

Comment: Make sure you don't include `SDL2` twice. If you use `-I/usr/include/SDL2` and `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`, the compiler will be looking for `/usr/include/SDL2/SDL2/SDL.h`

Answer (score 1):

SDL2 headers should be included as follows:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

Not:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

### Why?

Because when you run `sdl2-config --cflags` its outputs a path like this `include/SDL2` and if you do a `ls` on it you will get `SDL.h` not `SDL2/SDL.h`.

Comment: But as I described in my post, `make`ing when configured for a *nix system works fine. You can see the output of the config cflag in the comment on the main post.

Comment: @Bloodyaugust it will be a configuration error, check your paths.

If you use `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` on unix-like systems it will work because the SDL2 is on the standard include path but it does not happens  on windows, so you will have to use `#include <SDL.h>`, any other error is from the configuration you have.